# Compiler: String constant vs dynamically-allocated String object

Tags: compiler-construction

I am writing a small compiler and I am having trouble to handle string constant and string object.

Take the following code for example:

```
s : String = "Hello world"
```

Since the string is in the program, this will be recognized by the compiler and a string constant will be generated and placed in the `.data` segment.

```
.data

string_const1:
    .quad    2
    .quad    6
    .quad    String_dispatch_table
    .quad    int_const1
    .asciz    "Hello world"
    .align    8
```

The actually string then can be accessed by:

```
leaq string_const1(%rip), %rax
addq $32, %rax
```

However, if we ask users to input a string, then the string object needs to be generated dynamically. Here is the string object template that is also placed in the `.data` segment.

```
String_protoObj:
    .quad    2                        # tag              
    .quad    5                        # size
    .quad    String_dispatch_table    
    .quad    0                        # string length
    .quad    0                        # string content

# assume %rax contains the address of a copy of String_protoObj
# assume %rdi contains the address of user input string 

leaq String_protoObj(%rip), %rdi
callq malloc
movq user-input, %rdi
movq %rdi, 32(%rax)   # copy the new string into string content
```

Then later to access the actual string, i have to use

```
32(%rax)  # read from memory
```

**So there is a difference between accessing string from a string constant and a dynamically-allocated string object, which require different handle in all functions**

I could obviously add another tag in the protoObject to indicate this is an allocated object instead of a constant but this would require all the method who receives string object/constant to do a check and this does not sound elegant at all.

Can anyone please give me any suggestion of how I can handle this situation well?

Comment: Are your string objects​ immutable?

Comment: @rici No it is not. I first do a copy of the string protoObject and then movq the string content into it at offset 32 which is the last field

Comment: In that case, you will need some way to differentiate between constants and string objects, because constants are immutable and you cannot allow them to be mutated. (Unless your compiler takes the "give them enough rope to hang themselves and a warning not to use it" philosophy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd start by making the constant look like a string object, which means that the fifth word will contain a pointer to the sixth word. That's a price you're evidently willing to pay with string objects.

A more space efficient strategy is the one used by most modern C++ libraries, in which there are two string layouts: one with an included character vector (short strings) and the other with a pointer. You can tell them apart from the length so you don't need a different tag but of course you could also use a different tag.

In practice, most strings are reasonably short so this optimization is believed to be useful. But it's more work, and a lot more tests to write, so you might want to save it for later.

Comment: `making the constant look like a string object`, this is very interesting. Do you mind to elaborate on the implementation details for this in x86-64? How can i make a pointer for the fifth fields to point to the sixth?

Comment: @jackddddd: You know what the address will be, no? It's some fixed offset from `string_const1`. To be honest, I don't really understand the value 6 for the size of the string constant.

Comment: that should be 5 i guess i somehow got that wrong. So can i define the string content separately. like `string_content1 .string "Hello world"`. Then in `string_constr1` at the fifth field, instead of having `.asciz "hello world"`, i'll have `.quad string_content1`. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @Jackddddd: yep, seems reasonable.